# Trying to use REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL and SPLIT with SAFEOFFSET in Big Query

Tags: split, google-bigquery

I am trying to split multiple pieces of data within the same field (message) by a delimeter of '§' and put the split items into new rows.  For example, my data looks like this:

-ABC/12§HAVEANICEDAY§JANEDOE@EMAIL.COM§XXXXXXXXXXXX1234

The data can be any combination of symbols, letters and numbers both before and after the delimeters.  How do I get the data to look like this?

```
-ABC/12
HAVEANICEDAY
JANEDOE@EMAIL.COM
XXXXXXXXXXXX1234
```

I was trying to use a combination of REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(message, '*§'  and SPLIT(message, '§')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as Offset1, but I can't get any combination to work.   Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select part
from unnest(split('-ABC/12§HAVEANICEDAY§JANEDOE@EMAIL.COM§XXXXXXXXXXXX1234', '§')) part
```

with output

[image]